# Can I use explorer on the windows command line to open a folder shortcut in favorites?

Tags: windows, command-line, windows-explorer

I have a folder in my favorites and I can open the folder using `explorer \path\to\folder`, but I want the explorer window to show the shortcut to this folder in the favorites section (not the real path to the folder). Any ideas?

I tried things like `explorer favorites\path\to\folder` but that's not the actual path to the shortcut.

Answer (score 2):

I'm a little confused by the wording of the question, but if you are referring to the "Favorites", as in the Favorites that are linked on the side of *Windows Explorer* and not the "Favorites" that are listed in *Internet Explorer*, you should be able access this folder via:

```
explorer C:\Users\%USERNAME%\Links
```

As explained in one of the other answers, the *Internet Explorer* Favorites are available at

```
explorer C:\Users\%USERNAME%\Favorites
```

Do keep in mind though, that the stuff that is listed inside of that folder are just shortcuts to other folders, whether it be on your desktop or on a Network Drive.  If they are ever moved, the shortcuts inside of the Links folder may not work anymore.

Answer (score 0):

The "Favorites section" is just a folder in C:\Users\%username%\Favorites.

You can do `explorer C:\Users\%username%\Favorites` but it will show all the favorites.  No way to just cause it to open a box with a single file inside unless you put the shortcut in its own folder.

However, if you mean open a folder within your Favorites, you can certainly do that, `explorer c:\users\%username%\Favorites\Whatever Folder\etc`

If you just want to know what the shortcut points to, you can right click and look at the properties, or open Notepad, and drag the shortcut to the open Notepad instance.

Comment: I should have mentioned, there is the added difficulty that the shortcut points to a network drive: "\\CompName". So I tried things like `c:\users\%username%\Favorites\\CompName" but that didn't work.

Comment: Are you wanting to show the shortcut or what the shortcut points to?

Comment: I want the right hand side to show the contents of the folder the shortcut points to, and the navigation to show the shortcut under favorites.

Answer (score 0):

I think I understand what you are asking...

From the `command propmpt` type:

```
c:\>%USERPROFILE%\Favorites\"somefolder - shortcut.lnk"
```

Comment: I can't seem to get the right name of the folder within Favorites. It's actually a network drive that points to "\\CompName". How would I find the correct thing to fill in for "somefolder - shortcut.lnk"?

Comment: Looks like the name of the shortcut is "CompName.lnk", but I tried your suggestion and it doesn't work...

Comment: CD to %USERPROFILE%\Favorites and do a DIR

Comment: Nothing that interesting. The only relevant thing seems to be a folder "Links" but it is empty. (Other things include a bing.url file and a lenovo recommended websites folder)